# Vim open a certain size but return to terminal window size when closed

Tags: vim, terminal

So my terminal window size on MAC OS is 100 columns and 30 rows.

When I open `vim` like this `vim filename.txt` I want the size to open to whatever size is specified in `.vimrc` (this works).

The size in my `.vimrc` is 200 columns and 40 rows. When I quit vim with `:q` I want the size of the window to go back to the terminal size (100 columns and 30 rows) but it remains 200 columns and 40 rows. Is there a way to go back to 100 columns and 30 rows automatically when `vim` closes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim detects the existing terminal size and initializes the [`'columns'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27columns%27) and [`'lines'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27lines%27) option values. If you save these before overriding them, you can restore the original values on the [`VimLeave`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#VimLeave) event.

```
let g:save_columns = &columns
let g:save_lines = &lines
autocmd VimLeave * let &columns = g:save_columns | let &lines = g:save_lines
set columns=100 lines=30
```

In fact, as you define the `:autocmd` in your `~/.vimrc`, you don't need to use variables, but can simply encode the values inside the `:autocmd`:

```
execute printf('autocmd VimLeave * set columns=%d lines=%d', &columns, &lines)
set columns=100 lines=30
```